# R: Generalized linear mixed models (GLMM):STANDARDIZED COEFFIECIENT TO ODD RATIO?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, coefficients

I am currently analizying data on wild galliformes parasites.
I built a GLMM (GLMER FUNCTION IN LME4 PACKAGE) to assess the influence of selected risk factors on parasites distribution.
I standardized continuous explanatory variables (subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation :using "scale (.)"function in R. I then exponentiated the coefficients to the odds scale.
Would you calculate the odds ratios based on standardized coefficient estimates (interpreting as the odds ratio for an increase of one standard deviation in the predictor) or convert back to get Odds for the raw data?
In this latter case , how would you convert back the coefficients?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hi Anjeline, can you provide an example of your code, and dataset (do dput(<dataframe>) and paste output) and elaborate slightly more on where you are stuck?

Comment: And I can answer some your questions, try to avoid asking too many questions in one post. You don't need to convert your coefficients back to odds or log odds. It is your response variables that are transformed using logit. So you interpret your coefficients as change in log odds ratio per standard deviation of predictor

Comment: capillaria = mutate_at(capillaria, vars(DEM:Distance), funs(s = as.numeric( scale(.) ) ) )  #standardize with SCALE FUNCTION WHICH involves subtracting the mean and then dividing by the standard deviation. [model selection i would avoid to copy paste this long script ] 
fit12=glmer(CAPILLARIA  ~ Aspect+DEM_s+Y_s+Distance_s+Corine+ (1|MOUNTAIN), data=capillaria,family = binomial) #BEST MODEL ######CONFIDENCE INTERVAL ESTIMATES
se <- sqrt(diag(vcov(fit12)))
(tab <- cbind(Est = exp(fixef(fit12)), LL =exp(fixef(fit12) - 1.96 * se), UL = exp(fixef(fit12) + 1.96 *
                se)))

Comment: @StupidWolf .. what do you think about ? Could I interpret the odds as change in standard deviation of predictor .? Please not that I have transformed with scale (.) function meaning that I also substracted the mean before dividing by the standard deviation .. and I have apply this function only to the continuous variables  but I have also categorical variables .. so what is the best way to present the results? Do I need to get back the original coefficients before exponentiate ?or can I can exponentiate directly the standardized coefficients? Thanks